# NSPredicate filter class by CGPoint

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, cgpoint

I have that class :

```
@interface Field : NSObject
@property CGPoint fieldCoordinates;
@property CGPoint ballCoordinates;
@end
```

and i Try filter NSArray of object of  this class :

```
NSPredicate * y1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ballCoordinates.y >= %@",location.y];
NSArray * filtered = [self.fieldsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:y1];
```

but get error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key y.'

NSPredicate have problem with filter by CGPoint ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `NSPredicate` has problems with `CGPoint`, because it is a `struct`, not a key-value compliant Objective-C class. You can write a predicate with a block instead, like this:

```
NSPredicate * y1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bind) {
    return ((CGPoint)[obj ballCoordinates]).y >= location.y;
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

CGPoint is not an Object it's a plain old C struct.
You could walk around that by making a readonly property on your Field class that look like this.
`@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat yBallCoordinates;`
`- (CGFloat)yBallCoordinates { return self.ballCoordinates.y; }`

---

Edit
The block approach pointed by dasblinkenlight is a better solution.
Because it will not involve the necessity of declaring property for every thing you want to predicate on. Which will be more flexible.